# AJAX 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, api

I'm using ajax to consume a web service.

My first request is a POST to get the auth token. (It's working.)
But the second request is showing "401 (Unauthorized)".
What could be the problem here?

PS. I'm using CORS extension on Chrome. If I disable that I get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

When I use the same token on Postman(disabling SSL) my request is successful.
The same token also works with python "requests.get(urlShow, headers=bpHeader, verify=False)".

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'url',
data: {"authType" : "password", "username" : "<username>", "password" : "<password>", "tenant" : "<tenant>"},
success: function(bpResponse){
    var bpAuth = "Bearer " + bpResponse.token;
    console.log(bpAuth);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'url',
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": bpAuth},
        success: function(bpResources){
            console.log(bpResources);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

That's the console log I get:

[image]

Comment: Seems like your web service does not accept the token you are providing. It depends on the implementation of the service, how you need to pass the token back to the web service. What web service are you using? A custom one?

Comment: use option `headers`, not `header`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run chrome using:

```
"PATH:\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir --disable-web-security --ignore-certificate-errors --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests
```